How to make JSON.parse to not remove double quotes?
I have the following code snippet
console.log(JSON.parse('\"a string\"'))
console.log(JSON.parse('"a string"'))
console.log('a string')

You can try it here https://jsfiddle.net/s80rtf3u/
On jsfiddle, they all return the same string without the double quotes even for the first and second statement.
Is there a way to keep the double quotes with JSON.parse?

The complete JSON document "a string", as is expressed in both of your first two lines, is directly equivalent to a JavaScript string object "a string". If you need expression of the quotes themselves, you need to contain them within your JSON string object, a la "\"a string\"". In your example, this would look like console.log(JSON.parse('"\\"a string\\""')).

@thd: To avoid an XY problem, it would help if you could explain the context of this question in more detail. Why do you want the outer quotes to be kept when logging the parsed result?

"Is there a way to keep the double quotes with JSON.parse?" No. Does console.log('"' + JSON.parse('"a string"') + '"') solve your problem?

function customReplacer(key, value) {
  // Check if the value is a string
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
     // Replace all double quotes with their Unicode escape sequence
     return value.replace(/"/g, '\u0022');
  }
  // Return the value unmodified if it's not a string
  return value;
}
        
const obj = {
  example: 'This "is" a test.',
  another: "Here's another \"example\"."
};

const jsonString = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, customReplacer));      
console.log(jsonString);


{example: 'This "is" a test.', another: Here's another "example".}

And to answear the exact question - store the quote as Unicode.
